# ways to set/change/append to dojo-data-props

Tags: javascript, html, dojo, web

I would like to set the dojo-data-props of a dojo widjet but I don't want to do it in the declaration. I would like to do it from a script using some dojo function or js function.

Here is my widget declaration:

```
<input id="myTextBox" data-dojo-type="oneui.form.TextBox" />
```

I would like to set its dojo-data-props in a script right after

```
<script type="text/javascript"> Set dojo-data-props here </script>
```

Is there any way to do this?
I tried using dojo.attr but it did not work for dojo-data-props, only works for basic html attributes.

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to build the widget programatically in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call the set() method for the widjit you're using.

```
dojo.mywidget.set("myAttribute", value);
```